# How to specify annotations in VCD files?

Tags: linux, gtkwave, vcd

In a `VCD` file I would like to specify that some events occurred at a particular time. To that end, I tried to define a single bit signal which value is almost the time `0`, and switching this value to `0` and then back to `1` in the same time (at the time when my event occurs). Unfortunately nothing is displayed when looking into the file with `gtkwave`. How could I achieve this behavior ?

Comment: If you flip a signal without advancing time does this even get written to the VCD?  I would expect the signal to be either 0 or 1 or x but not to be able to see it go to 1 and back.

Comment: @dave I am generating a VCD file myself, so yes I can switch it on and off on the same time. Moreover, to my understanding the VCD file MUST be time ordered, do you confirm that ?

Comment: I still wouldn't expect it to show up in gtkwave: the VCD doesn't make sense .... a signal can't have two values at the same time.

Comment: Ok thank you for clear answer. So do you think there is a mean to show an "instantaneous" event in a VCD file ?

Comment: No there isn't but you could use a time interval that is less than your other time intervals (e.g. some small fraction of the clock)

Comment: Ok thank you again. To do that I would have to set a time resolution lower than my clock cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event as your variable data type and use -> to force an event on it.  It will show up in gtkwave as an impulse arrow in zero time.  No tricks with timescales are necessary.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for ! Neverthless, I am not able to find the right syntax to raise the event at a particular time (event definition is correct), can you please show an exemple ? Also, is there any definitive documentation of the VCD file format ?

Comment: Here's an example:

    module top;
    event a;
    initial
    begin
    $dumpfile("whatever.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0, top);
    #10 ->a;
    #10 ->a;
    #10 ->a;
    #10 ->a;
    #10 ->a;
    end
    endmodule

Comment: For VCD syntax, you can look in the Verilog spec.